# Ping to a specific IP address using python

Tags: python, network-programming, ip-address, ping, icmp

I want to write a python script that should check if a particular IP address is reachable or not. I'm new to python programming and have no idea how the code might look. Help out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the subprocess module and shlex module to parse the shell command like below

```
import shlex
import subprocess

# Tokenize the shell command
# cmd will contain  ["ping","-c1","google.com"]     
cmd=shlex.split("ping -c1 google.com")
try:
   output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError,e:
   #Will print the command failed with its exit status
   print "The IP {0} is NotReacahble".format(cmd[-1])
else:
   print "The IP {0} is Reachable".format(cmd[-1])
```

Comment: Can you please brief 'shlex' in this context? Also, can this be done without using 'shlex'?

Comment: @Goblin The shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args( for unix shell) , Yes it can be done without shlex in that case you have to tokenize your command like cmd=["ping","-c1","google.com"] as list and pass to subprocess.check_ouptut this work is done by shlex.split() for you. for shlex reference read this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html

Comment: it is the case when `rc = subprocess.call()` could be used. No need to raise exception if it is expected.

Answer (score 8):

You can try like this;

```
>>> import os
>>> if os.system("ping -c 1 google.com") == 0:
...     print "host appears to be up"
```

Comment: Note that this isn't cross-platform.